# cucumber scenarios relationship with test definition

Tags: cucumber

I have very simple question. i tried hard to find its answer on internet but could not succeed.
I have one feature file and it has 4 scenarios as following

**Feature:** Account Management

**Scenario:** Add Account

**Scenario:** Remove Account

**Scenario:** Delete Account

**Scenario:** Update Account

**Q:** Do i require to develop test_definition file separately for each scenario and place all of them under same directory i.e. `\features\step_definitions`

Answer (score 0):

You can organise your step definitions however you like, so long as they are in/under features/step_definitions.

I'd recommend starting by organising them by topic, so start with account_steps, and see how you get along. Break into smaller files when you need to (not before you need to).